# web page with 3 different colors, 1cm margins, not getting desired results

Tags: html, css

I want to divide my web page into 3 divs, with 3 different colors, When I use `width:100%`, 1 centimetre of margins are empty and have not that color.

What should I do to fix this problem?

Example of the problem:

[image]

Fix sample

[image]

Comment: start using firebug "the helping hand of every developer"

Answer (score 2):

Try to put

```
html, body {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

into your CSS, which should do the magic

Comment: @user, please, press that tick on the left, which marks the answer correct.

Answer (score 2):

Apply this..

```
body
{
 margin:0;
 padding:0;
}
```

if you are using those number's in "p" or any "h1-h6" tag
apply the same

```
margin:0;
padding:0;
```

One more tip i would like to give you to use Firebug which you have in your browser :

mouse hover the body or any other element just to confirm whether they are having any default padding or margin... 
this thing will help you in the future to do small things very fast..

[image]

the yellow color indicates default/applied margin and purple color indicates default/applied padding on any element.

hope this will help you in future also.

in-case you don't know : [what is firebug and how to use this](http://templatic.com/theme-support/tips-n-tutorials/how-to-use-firebug/)

Comment: select any answer which was helpful to you and close this question

Answer (score 1):

```
<style>
  body {margin:0;}
</style>
```

Comment: Most people would if the answer uses inline styles as opposed to preferred style sheet approach.

Comment: so you want me to post a completely valid html-document with doctype and anything just to suggest one css-property? that's ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

you can clear all padding and margins with an css reset:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/